# Cannot import installed python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

```py
from binance.spot import Spot

client = Spot()

# Get server timestamp
print(client.time())
```

I installed the module with the pip install command, but I get the “ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance.spot'; 'binance' is not a package” error. Also, when I run the file with py extension in another directory, it works without errors.

When I type the pip list command, I can see it in the list.

2 versions of Python were installed. I uninstalled both 3.9 and 3.11. I cleaned the python framework folders in the Library folder and installed python 3.10.

Comment: Could you please specify what module you tried to install and your code?

Comment: Is this in a virtual environment? (If not and you have multiple versions of Python: _definitely_ use a virtual environment) instead of trying to make things work globally when what you need is only relevant to a specific project.

Comment: You said "No module named...".  Why would you remove the most important piece of information?  Just post the whole dang error message.

Comment: You are right. I added the entire error message.

Comment: Do you have __init__ file in your module?

Comment: Did you install `binance-connector`? https://github.com/binance/binance-connector-python

Comment: Please show your pip install commands, that would help here as well.

Comment: Yes, the module I have problems with is binance-connector.

Comment: @joanis  The command I wrote is `pip install binance-connector`. 
Output is `Requirement already satisfied: binance-connector in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (3.5.1)` etc...

Comment: @ngeof94 Yes, there is an empty __init__.py file

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans No, not in a virtual environment. There is now only one version available. 3.10.11

Comment: Do you have a local `binance.py` file in the folder you're running your code in? This is a very common problem, where you name your script after the package it's going to test out, but it masks the installed package by mistake.

Comment: Tested, and it works fine for me. Most often it is some kind of environment issue. I know you've been working at that and you're saying there's only one environment, but keep digging, it's the kind of problem that causes these errors.

Comment: Sometimes `pip` comes from the wrong place, in which case `python -m pip install binance-connector` might give you a different answer than just `pip install binance-connecter`.  Try `which pip` and `which python` (Linux/Mac) or `where pip` and `where python` (Windows). If they're not coming from the same place, that's likely your problem.

Comment: @Blckknght Must be a joke. That's the problem. I changed the name and fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: This is exactly why you _always_ want to use virtual environments. They get their own copy of the python executable, and pip script. Once active, there is no "I'm accidentally using the wrong one".